# process.waitFor() throws IllegalThreadStateException

Tags: java, java-process-runtime

**Environment**

> ```
> Windows 10
> Java 1.8
> ```

**Process**

```
I am running a 7zip's zip task.
The process takes 2 to 3 hours to complete.
```

**Exception**

> java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process has not exited
> at java.lang.ProcessImpl.exitValue(ProcessImpl.java:443)
> at java.lang.ProcessImpl.waitFor(ProcessImpl.java:452at

**My code**

```
int exitValue = -1;
Process start = null;
try
{
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
        start = processBuilder.start();
        try(BufferedReader ipBuf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(start.getInputStream())))
        {
            String line = null;
            while ((line = ipBuf.readLine()) != null)
            {
                LOGGER.info(line);
            }
        }
        try(BufferedReader errBuf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(start.getErrorStream())))
        {
            String line;
            while ((line = errBuf.readLine()) != null)
            {
                LOGGER.warning(line);
            }
        }
        start.waitFor();
        exitValue = start.exitValue();
}
finally
{
        if (start != null)
        {
            start.destroy();
        }
}
return exitValue;
```

I'm unable to find the root cause of this issue.

> **Note:** I've tried this process with a similar demo instance on the same
> machine and it works fine.

Please help me resolve this, Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this issue: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8042019

Comment: @Holger ... which is caused by a spectacularly brain-dead Windows implementation of `GetExitCodeProcess` that would be funny if it wasn't tragic.  Java can't fix this.

Comment: I'm seeing this problem in Linux also

Comment: @JimGarrison it is not true that Java can't fix this. It can, but doesn't seem to care. The problem is that the method `waitFor()` calls `exitValue()` (see [source](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/windows/classes/java/lang/ProcessImpl.java#L483)). The latter throws an exception because it receives the exit code 259 and thinks the process hasn't exited. This could easily be fixed because when `waitFor()` calls `exitValue()`, it knows at that point that the process has exited, and it should check the exit value using a new method that doesn't throw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is caused by the [Windows ProcessBuilder exit code 259 bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8042019) then there are workarounds available: all you need to do to make sure that your sub-process does not exit with status code 259 and Windows JRE won't report `java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException`.

**UPDATE**

The status 259 bug on Windows was fixed in JDK20, see [JDK-8294899](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8294899), so answer below is only helpful for earlier JDK.

You can easily reproduce this issue by executing the following command with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)` or `ProcessBuilder(cmd)`:

```
String[] cmd = {"cmd.exe /c exit /b 259"};
```

If you have written the code for the sub-process then just edit your code so that exit code is never set to 259.

If you have not written the code for the sub-process then a rather hacky workaround is to wrap your Java sub-process launch with a "CMD.EXE" and mini-script which adapts non-zero sub-process exit back to exit codes 0 or 1:

```
String[] fixed = new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/c", 
        "(call "+String.join(" ", cmd)+ ") || (echo !!! DETECTED ERROR!!! && exit 1)" };
```

**Note**: I'm no expert on CMD. The above fix **definitely won't work** for certain commands or punctuation (eg those with quotes / spaces etc), and because it runs under CMD.EXE environment settings the outcome might be different to direct launch from the calling JVM.

Here is an example class you could test with:

```
/** Examples to test with and without the fix:

 java Status259 "cmd.exe /c exit /b 0"
 java Status259 "cmd.exe /c exit /b 25"
 java Status259 "cmd.exe /c exit /b 259"

 java Status259 %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -cp your.jar Status259$StatusXXX 0
 java Status259 %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -cp your.jar Status259$StatusXXX 33
 java Status259 %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java -cp your.jar Status259$StatusXXX 259
 */
public class Status259 {

    public static class StatusXXX {
        public static void main(String ... args) {
            int status = args.length > 0 ? Integer.parseInt(args[0]) : 0;
            System.out.println("StatusXXX exit code: "+status);
            System.exit(status);
        }
    }

    public static int exec(String[] cmd) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        System.out.println("exec "+Arrays.toString(Objects.requireNonNull(cmd)));

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
        // No STDERR => merge to STDOUT - or call redirectError(File)
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process p = pb.start();

        // send sub-process STDOUT to the Java stdout stream
        try(var stdo = p.getInputStream()) {
            stdo.transferTo(System.out);
        }

        int rc = p.waitFor();

        System.out.println("exec() END pid="+p.pid()+" CODE "+rc +' '+(rc == 0 ? "OK":"**** ERROR ****"));

        return rc;
    }

    public static void main(String ... args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {    
        // COMMENT OUT NEXT LINE TO SEE EFFECT OF DIRECT LAUNCH:
        args = fixStatus259(args);

        int rc = exec(args);
        System.exit(rc);
    }

    private static String[] fixStatus259(String[] cmd) {
        System.out.println("fixStatus259 "+Arrays.toString(cmd));
        return new String[] {
            "cmd.exe", "/c",
            "(call "+String.join(" ", cmd)+ ") || (echo !!! DETECTED ERROR!!! && exit 1)"
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, the JDK bug mentioned in this answer is actually fixable; in fact a fix is very simple and may even be fixed by the time you read this. See [bug details](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8294899).

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to your problem:

1. The JDK has a bug which causes an exception to be thrown when a Windows process returns an exit code of 259.
2. The command that you pass to ProcessBuilder exits with an exit code of 259 when it shouldn't.

Tackling each point in turn:

1. The [bug in the JDK](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8294899) is caused by the following flawed logic in the Windows-specific implementation of [Process.waitFor()](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/windows/classes/java/lang/ProcessImpl.java#L566): First, it waits until the process exits. Then, it calls `exitValue()` to get the exit value from the process. But unfortunately `exitValue()` gets the exit value and then checks if it's a special value that indicates the process hasn't exited. Since `waitFor()` knows that the process *has* exited, it should get the exit value directly instead of calling this method which does an unwanted check. Hopefully the JDK developers will fix this bug soon.

UPDATE: This bug was fixed in Java 21.

2. You should be using the command-line version of 7-zip, `7z.exe` which exits with a set of [well-defined exit values](https://documentation.help/7-Zip/exit_codes.htm) (so it never returns 259).